# Does British English use the term "heel" for the end slice of bread?

Tags: british-english, hiberno-english

I'm Irish, and hence speak Hiberno-English. Here is a photograph of some sliced bread:

[image: sliced bread]

The topmost slice of this (that's crust on the end), is called "the heel". Is this meaning for "heel" understood in British English?

Comment: It's the heel in American English too.

Comment: @rory -- it's the **"doupie"**, do you use that one?

Comment: Another interesting more American one is **"butt-end"**.  Also for the, well, butt-end of perhaps a ham or other roast meat.  (The last, or perhaps first, slice.)

Comment: I'm English and when I first met my Irish wife this one caused confusion / hilarity, especially when combined with the Irish term 'pan' for a loaf of bread e.g. "can you get me the heel from that pan"

Comment: No, we don't know the term "doupie". Although "butt-end" would not be used, a person might reason it out. Also this question is inspired by a similar mixed marriage.

Comment: @JoeBlow  Only a down-at-heel gentleman-of-the-road would harvest a discarded 'butt-end" and that would be to satisfy his addiction to nicotine. I don't want to be a heel, but I have to declare that such practices are a tad nauseating. Perish the thought!

Answer (score 10):

Further to what others have said, I (growing up in London and York) was familiar with *heel* to mean that slice, but it wasn’t common — the usual term for that slice was *the crust*.  (So *crust* had a dual meaning for us — both the outside of the bread in general, and the slice at either end that consists mostly of crust.)

Comment: I would certainly agree with _crust_. Lived most of my life in North-East England and have _never_ heard the term _heel_ before and wouldn't have had a clue what you were talking about. Straw-poll of those nearby suggests it's NOT a commonly understood phrase (out of a dozen people, only an Irishman had heard it before)

Comment: For the record PLL, I have never ever heard the doupie called the "crust".  (i.e., have never, ever, heard the dual meaning you describe.)  So perhaps, very regional?

Comment: Interesting — yes, perhaps!  And I in turn have never heard *doupie* — where does that term come from?

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't use it myself, but I have heard it - though in a slightly different sense. I wouldn't understand "the piece of a sliced loaf that happens to be the crust" so much as "an unsliced loaf from which all but a couple of slices have been cut".

Comment: Interesting. They have unsliced bread in England? Next you'll be telling me it isn't white and as squishy as Play-Doh either. :-)

Comment: I had no choice but buy a sliced loaf on Sunday, because that was all they had left before they closed (yes, our mediaeval laws mean that even 24-hour stores have to close for most of Sunday). But it's a long time since the last time I did.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is understood in British English too; one of the meaning of *heel* reported by the NOAD and the OED is the following:

> a crusty end of a loaf of bread, or the rind of a cheese.

Comment: I would say it's only known in BE as an American import. I never heard it in northern English before living in the USA

Comment: Well, OED has it in *Piers Plowman* 1362, a bit early for an American import...

Answer (score 1):

I'm Irish but my parents are English. I'd certainly understand *heel*, but in our house it's called *the dobie end*. I have no idea what the origin of that phrase is.

Comment: Fascinating - in Scotland that word sounds more like "dowpy" or perhaps "doopy"

Answer (score 1):

I am Irish-American and both sets of my grandparents (raised by Irish immigrants) and my parents referred to the ends of a loaf of bread as the *humbo*.

Comment: I tried Googling for references but didn't find any :(

Answer (score 1):

60% of the US who are ancestors of European immigrants use the term "heel" for the end of a loaf of bread. It shows this amount on the US Dialect survey map. I found it on Google. Especially NJ and NY have used this word the most.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The question is about terminology in British English, not in the U.S. If you are unfamiliar with Stack Exchange, please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site; the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will offer additional guidance.

Comment: Do you mean "descendants" of European immigrants? It would be useful to show some link to current British-English usage.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the term heel but then, although growing up in London, I came from Irish parents.

Answer (score 0):

I call it the heel, and I'm sure I learned that word from my mum who was born in Durham England. She 'came over' as a child with her parents and 3 sisters  in 1920 or thereabouts, and ended up in Pennsylvania.
I think all my cousins and nieces and nephews know the word 'heel' as it relates to a loaf of bread.

Comment: Yes, I was feeling this was used in the North of England...